# Issues with a responsive iFrame

Tags: iframe, resize, responsive

I'm still learning coding and have come across issues with sizing a responsive iFrame. The issue is that on non-mobile devices the iframe is too tall and on standard and larger screens the video is blurred.

Here is the html:
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gBwbB49yqFY" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

I had hoped that adding the 16 by 9 element would equate to an upper limit on the size but that is not the case. Is it possible to scale it so that it not only fits but is not 100% of the screen height? Thanks in advance:)